How to Avoid Using --run-syncdb with python manage.py migrate
I am working on a Django project that I cloned from GitHub. When I try to run python manage.py migrate, it fails and requires me to use --run-syncdb. However, I want to make it so that python manage.py migrate is sufficient without the need for --run-syncdb.
I noticed that there is no migrations folder in my project. Here are the steps I have taken so far:

Verified that the project does not have any existing migration files.
Tried to run python manage.py makemigrations to generate migration files, but it still fails.

It fails because after python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate I get no migrations folder in my apps.
How can I resolve this issue and ensure that python manage.py migrate works without requiring --run-syncdb? Is there a specific reason why the migrations folder might be missing, and how can I recreate it?

How does thiscommand fails? Please include it in your question

After python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate I get no migrations folder in my apps.

You must add "migrations" folder in the app directory with empty init.py file inside. Then you can just do "makemigrations" which should create 0001_initial.py migration.
